# Conditions for existence of a viscoity or mild a solution

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, viscosity-solutions

Suppose I have a PDE of the form
$$
0=-\partial_t f(t,z) + \phi(0,z)+ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} b_i(t,z)\partial_{z_i}f(t,z)
+
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^{\infty} a_{i,j}(t,z)(\partial_{z_j}\partial_{z_i}f(t,z) - g(\partial_{z_i}\partial_{z_j}f(t,z)),
$$
where $g$ is a $C^{\infty}$, strictly convex function on $\mathbb{R}$.

What conditions do I *need* to impose on $a_{i,j}$, $b_i$ and $g$ in order to assure that the above PDE has a (preferably unique) mild viscosity solution?

**Note:**
*(If this problem is too difficult, we may assume that the $a_{i,j}$, $b_i$ and $g$ are continuous, but I prefer not to have to).*

Comment: Is this an infinite-dimensional problem, or are the limits of summation a typo?

Comment: The equation is third order, right? So there is no notion of viscosity solution since the maximum principle only works for first or second order equations. What do you mean by "mild" solution?

Comment: Second order, the last $\partial_{z_i}$ was a typo, thanks for pointing that out